# Open Weather Api FreeCodeCamp not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following snippet is not displaying anything. Here's my code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/EZMJZw). Could you help me figure out what's wrong and how to fix it? I also checked, and the API links are correct.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".cityarea").html(getLocation);
  testMenu();
  
});
 
  var currentLat;
  var currentLong;
  var currentCity;
  var currentRegion;
  var currentCountry;
  
  var mainCities = {
    'San_Francisco': {
      'region': 'California',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 37.7749300,
      'lon': -122.4194200
    },
    'St._Louis': {
      'region': 'Missouri',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 38.6272700,
      'lon': -90.1978900
    },
    'Miami': {
      'region': 'Florida',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 25.7742700,
      'lon': -80.1936600
    },
    'Tokyo': {
      'region': 'Tokyo',
      'country': "Japan",
      'lat': 35.689500,
      'lon': 139.6917100
    },
    'Denver': {
      'region': 'Colorado',
      'country': "United States",
      'lat': 39.739100,
      'lon': -104.984700
    }
  };
  
  function testMenu() {
    for (var place in mainCities) {
      var city = place.replace(/_/g, ' ');
      $('#testMenu').append("<li onclick=testWeather('" + place + "');><a href='#'>" + city + "</a></li>");
    }
  };
  
  function testWeather(cityLocation) {
    
    currentLat = mainCities[cityLocation].lat;
    currentLong = mainCities[cityLocation].lon;
    currentRegion = mainCities[cityLocation].region;
    currentCity =cityLocation.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    currentCountry = mainCities[cityLocation].country;
    
    getWeather();
    
  };
  
  function getLocation() {
    $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json', function(data) {
      
      currentRegion = data.regionName;
      //currentCity = data.city;
      currentCountry = data.country;
      currentLat = data.lat;
      currentLong = data.lon;
      
      getWeather();
      
    });
  };
  
function getWeather() {
  
  $("#state").text(currentRegion);
  $("#country").text(currentCountry);
  
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + currentLat + '&lon=' + currentLong + '&units=imperial&APPID=e656b9ee098cf2341fcfdb365b96b4a8', function(json) {
    
    $("#cityname").text(json.name);
    
    var showfahrenheit = true;
    var tempfahrenheit = Math.round(json.main.temp);
    var temcelcius = Math.round((tempfahrenheit - 32) * 5/9);
    
    $("#temp").html(tempfahrenheit);
    
    $('#unit-switch').on('click', function() {
      if (showfahrenheit === false) {
        $("#temp").html(tempfahrenheit);
        showfahrenheit = true;
      } else {
        $("#temp").html(temcelcius); 
        showfahrenheit = false;
      }
      
      $("#unit-toggle").toggleClass("toggle");
   
    });
    
     var prefix = "wi wi-owm-";
    var weatherIcons = json.weather[0].id;
    var icon = prefix + weatherIcons;
    
 $("#wparameter").html("<i class='" + icon + "'></i>");   $("#wdescription").text(json.weather[0].description);
   
      var weatherImages = {
  'rain': 'https://s6.postimg.org/7ug4yocip/rainpic1.jpg', 'clear': 'https://s6.postimg.org/alzepab1d/clearskypic1.jpg',
    'snow': 'https://s6.postimg.org/rdkq81ba9/snowpic.jpg',
    'clouds': 'https://s6.postimg.org/4v4mxtdnl/cloudspic.jpg',
    'fog': 'https://s6.postimg.org/r9mbe1gf5/fogpic.jpg',
    'thunder': 'https://s6.postimg.org/qpbvp3ckh/thunderstormpic.jpg',
    'windy': 'https://s6.postimg.org/wg222tkkh/windybreezepic.jpg',
    'dust': 'https://s6.postimg.org/tpo4rvyht/dustsandpic.jpg',
    'tornadostorm': 'https://s6.postimg.org/aamjq9jz5/tornadostorm.jpg'
};
      
      var imagepic;
      
      if (weatherIcons >= 200 && weatherIcons <= 232 ) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.thunder;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 300 && weatherIcons <= 531) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.rain;   
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 600 && weatherIcons <= 622) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.snow;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 701 && weatherIcons <= 731) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.dust;
      } else if (weatherIcons == 741) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.fog;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 751 && weatherIcons <= 781) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.dust;
      } else if (weatherIcons == 800) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.clear;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 801 && weatherIcons <= 804) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.clouds;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 900 && weatherIcons <= 906) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.tornadostorm;
      } else if (weatherIcons >= 951 && weatherIcons <= 962) {
        imagepic = weatherImages.windy;
      } else {}
      
      var speedimg = 500;
    
     $(".wrapper").animate({opacity: 0}, speedimg, function() {
       
       $(".wrapper").animate({opacity: 1}, speedimg);
       $(".wrapper").css(
    'background-image', 'url(' + imagepic + ')');
       
     });
    
  });
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
body {
  position: relative;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35%;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #009688;
  /*padding: 10px 20px;*/
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #000000;
}
.weatherbox {
  text-align: center;
}
.locationbox {
  position: relative;
   display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content:         center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content:         space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px;
}
.locactioninfobox {
  /* -webkit-flex-basis: 350px;
  flex-basis:         350px;*/
  text-align: left;
}
.cityarea h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
.countryarea {
  position: relative;
   display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /*-webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content:         center;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
.countryarea h3 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
}
.countryarea h3:first-child {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.dropdownlocation {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #777;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown > span {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.dropdown span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #57A0D4;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.dropdown span .fa {
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown span .fa-globe {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.dropdown > span,
.dropdown > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.dropdown > div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown > span:focus ~ div {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown > ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /*display: none;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
.dropdown > span:focus ~ ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li{
  /*padding: 15px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #4FB9A7;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #4FB9A7;
  color: #FFF;
}
ul .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.mainline hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.temperaturearea {
  padding: 0px 20px 10px;
}
.toptempbox {
  position: relative;
   display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content:         center;
}
.tempbox {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 180px;
  flex-basis:         180px;
}
.temperaturearea span#temp {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
}
.temperaturearea #temp:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 16px;
    right: -17px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.wconditionsbox {
   -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  padding-left: 5px;
   -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-basis:         100px;
}
.wconditionsbox span {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
#wparameter {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
#wdescription {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#wparameter, #wdescription {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.weather > span {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000000;
}
.weather > span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.main-toggle span {
  margin: 0 0 0 16px;
}
.main-toggle span:last-child {
  margin-left: 11px;
}
.weather button {
  background: #6bbf6b;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s;
}
.weather button:active {
  background: #67b567;
 }
.weather #unit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -8px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: left .2s;
}
#unit-toggle.toggle {
  left: 16px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   .container {
  width: 85%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
  width: 65%;
  min-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Local Weather</title>
</head>

<body class="full">
  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"><h1></h1></div>
    <div class="weatherbox">
      <div class="locationbox">
        <div class="locactioninfobox">
      <div class="cityarea">
      <h2 id="cityname"></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="countryarea">
        <h3 id="state"></h3>
        <h3 id="country"></h3>
      </div>
        </div>
      <div class="dropdownlocation">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <span tabindex="0" onclick="return true"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <div tabindex="0" onclick="return true"></div>
    <ul id="testMenu">
        <li onclick="getLocation();"><a href="#">Current Location</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Main Cities</li>
    </ul>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainline"><hr></div>
    <div class="temperaturearea">
      <div class="toptempbox">
        <div class="tempbox">
      <span id="temp"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="wconditionsbox">
          <span id="wparameter"></span>
      <span id="wdescription"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="weather main-toggle"> <!-- Begin Unit Switch -->
      <span>F</span>
      <button id="unit-switch"><span id="unit-toggle"></span></button>
      <span>C</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You sure you haven't just exceeded your daily quota of API access?

Comment: My Open Weather App is a free plan with limits Threshold: 7,200, Hourly forecast: 5, Daily forecast: 0, Calls 1min: 60. But I couldn't find anything to find out if I did exceed my quota. I just didn't think that many people were able to view my codepen a lot...

Comment: That is very likely...

Comment: https://openweathermap.org/appid said that if I exceed the limit, I should get a notification will be send to me. But I didn't get anything. So I'll email them. Anyway, does the code seems fine to you?

Comment: look at **developer** tools console - see the error `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ip-api.com/json"` ... that codepen works if you load http rather than https - http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/EZMJZw ... browser **developer** tools are useful tools for developing for a browser

Comment: your temperature scale button is broken if you change cities in celcius mode at least - button ends up inverse of what scale is displayed, and can also end up not moving, even though scale changes - I'm guessing you end up with multiple click events on that "button" - because every time you call `getWeather` you execute `$('#unit-switch').on('click', function() {`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks so much for explaining what's wrong! It's now displaying the temperature and weather. About the toggle button, what do you suggest I fix?

Comment: something like `$('#unit-switch').off('click');` before the `$('#unit-switch').on('click' ...`

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Could you add your answer to the post so that I can upvote your post and check your post as an answer, please?